# "compiled against a different mode version" Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am currently making a discord bot, I have just updated my `replit` to V13. v13 requires node.js V16+ so using a bit of `shell commands` I did it, I have done it now a numerous amount of times but now I am receiving this error:

```
Error: The module '/home/runner/IDK-any-name/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using "npm rebuild" or "npm install").
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at bindings (/home/runner/IDK-any-name/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/IDK-any-name/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may execute this to clean npm cache and reinstall all your dependencies this would allow you to compile better-sqlite-3 to your newly installed node version :

```sh
    rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm 
    cache clear --force && npm cache clean --force && npm i
```

Comment: `rm: cannot remove 'package-lock.json': No such file or directory`
I am getting that when I did that

Comment: It might have not created one for you, don't worry simply exclude it and run this ```rm -rf node_modules && npm 
    cache clear --force && npm cache clean --force && npm i```

Comment: this actually worked for me, thanks.